# What will happen if I delete satellite uplink?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I want to change one of my uplinks to nexus.

If I delete uplink what will happen? Will extra satellites stop working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't remove a satellite uplink unless you have the capacity to support your existing satellites.